# How to install wxpython on centos 6.5 (python 2.7)?

Tags: linux, python, centos-6

I've updated python on my centos to 2.7 and installed [wxpython](http://www.wxpython.org/) via:

```
yum install python-wx
```

Unfortunately python can't find the library and I get an error:

> ImportError: No module named wx

Did I forgot something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add repository below to get wxPython in CentOS 6.5. Then go to
*System > Administration > System > Add/Remove Software > Refresh Package Lists* and find **wxPython**.

```
rpm -Uvh http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm
```